# Why isn't there a for_each member function for each collection type in stl?

Tags: c++, stl, foreach, standards

For example:

```
v.for_each([](int i) { printf("%d\n", i); });
```

if far more elegant and readable than the commonly-used:

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int i) { printf("%d\n", i); });
```

Is there a legitimate reason such a member function is missing from the standard?

Comment: why would you require it? member functions only serve the purpose if the implementation can be made more efficient (set::find is more efficient than std::find() on a set). Oh, and if you want to avoid ubiquitous `.begin()`, en `.end()` calls, use [Boost Range Algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/introduction.html). Sweet syntactic sugar

Comment: @sehe: or *less* efficient, like `std::list::sort()` :-)

Comment: @Kerrek: `std::list::sort` is special, `std::sort` requires `RandomAccessIterator`, so it could not work for lists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the standard design rationale for the entire library: Separate containers from algorithms.

If you did it your way, you'd have to implement every feature X for every container Y, leading you to M * N implementations if you have M features and N containers.

By using iterators and make algorithms work on iterators rather than containers, you only have to implement M algorithms plus N iterator interfaces.

This separation also means that you have infinitely wider scope of application: the algorithms cannot just be used for *every* library container, but for *any* container, present or future, that anyone decides to write and equip with iterators. Finite vs infinite reuse is quite a strong argument! And calling the algorithms through the generic, free interface doesn't add any cost.

Comment: Mixins can be used to alleviate this problem- you can write a functionality mixin that is generic *and* works on any container.

Comment: @DeadMG: How would you use mixing to do a for-each on, say, a collection of regular expression matches or directory traversal?

Comment: The container inherits from the mixin, which uses iterators under the hood to provide the functionality. As long as the object provides iterators- exactly as they do now- then the mixin can convert that support into simple member functions with the interface shown in the OP. In addition, it's actually *more* generic because you can override the functionality in the container class yourself if you need to- e.g., `std::list`.

Comment: @DeadMG: I suppose that's possible, though it would also add tighter coupling between the algorithms and the containers - each time you write a new algorithm, you have to redefine all your container classes... I guess one could offer mixins as optional tools, but for a general design philosophy they don't seem as elegant as the current solution.

Comment: Not at all. The containers inherit from the mixin. When you change the mixin, they inherit the new functionality seamlessly.

Comment: @DeadMG: But how does the one super-mixin know about all algorithms, past, present and future? How does this scale and offer the same unbounded extensibility that iterators and algorithms do? Both algorithms and containers can come from many different, unrelated sources.

Comment: It doesn't know about all algorithms. Ideally, you would use extension methods (a'la C#) to plug that specific gap. However, it *is* generic to all containers *and* all iterators, because it's based directly on their functionality. More importantly, there's no reason not to offer a superior interface as Standard just because some other interfaces wouldn't be as good. And it is superior, because it's much more customizable by the specific container at hand, *and* it can be lazily evaluated and chained in a way the existing algorithms can't, like LINQ, *and* the interface is cleaner.

Comment: More than that, not *every* range can be expressed as a pair of iterators. Offering member functions allows you to have, say, a pair of iterators and a std::set to implement your range.

Comment: @DeadMG: I like the "lazily evaluated" bit, the Standard Library lacks the concepts of "Views". And I'll freely admit that meddling with iterator pairs is annoying... but not being familiar with C# I don't really understand the rest of your command, would you mind pointing me at an example of mix-in in C# ?

Comment: @Matthieu: C# doesn't have mixins- I was referring to extension methods, where you can make a free function that acts as if it's a class member. In this case, you would simply make an extension method for the mixin and all classes that inherit from it would gain that functionality.

Comment: @DeadMG: well, how would it be different from `for_each(mycontainer, myfunc);` ?

Comment: @Matthieu: It's not, substantially. It is, however, much better than `std::for_each(mycontainer.begin(), mycontainer.end(), myfunc);`.

Comment: @DeadMG: I agree, I never understood why they didn't special case algorithms for whole containers. With some SFINAE it's easy to detect the presence of `begin/end` members, and from there forward the call to the iterator versions... I *know* I can define those containers versions myself (and I do), but... :/

Answer (score 2):

```
template <class InputIterator, class UnaryFunction>
UnaryFunction for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, UnaryFunction f);
```

As you can see for_each takes Input Iterator as in parameter, so any stl container that can provide a input iterator compatible(meaning apart from input iterator, it could also be bidirectional ,random access iterator etc) would be compatible with std::for_each. By designing this way, stl generic  separate algorithm from data type(containers) which is more elegant & generic.

Answer (score 1):

The simple fact is that the Standard library design is from a time when the language did not offer many features, and many designs common now, such as CRTP-based mixins, weren't around. This means that superior designs that are obvious now simply weren't implementable or designable when the Standard library was created.

Iterators make a great generic implementation, but they make a sucky generic interface. I find it saddening that instead of solving the problem with the library design and overhauling it, instead they introduced one special case language feature for one tiny subset of the problem.

Comment: Could you show a little example of a mixin that can adapt to any future container and future algorithm?

Comment: @Kerrek: It doesn't have to. We can just use the existing support for future algorithms, future containers can just inherit from it, and we can get something better for the algorithms that are most used.

Comment: I see. Well, it would be nice to offer this. Sounds like this could be added as an optional feature set...

Answer (score 0):

Why would you require it?

Member functions only serve the purpose if the implementation can be made more efficient (set::find is more efficient than std::find() on a set).

**PS** Oh, and if you want to avoid ubiquitous `.begin()`, en `.end()` calls, use **[Boost Range Algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/introduction.html)**. Sweet syntactic sugar

A random Boost Range inspired sample:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/pending/integer_range.hpp>

using namespace boost::adaptors;

static int mod7(int v) 
    { return v % 7; }

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    boost::copy(
            boost::make_integer_range(1,100) | transformed(mod7), 
            std::back_inserter(v));

    boost::sort(v);

    boost::copy(
            v | reversed | uniqued, 
            std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
}
```